# Django/Ubuntu 16.04/ Specifying python version

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

Long story short....
When my Django project was on my computer(and not live on internet), I could specify which python version to use(I have both python2.7 and python3.6) like...

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

This was convenient because python 3 doesn't trigger unicode key errors when I try to run a string in different language, like korean. However now I have my website live on the internet using ubuntu 16.04 and it automatically uses python 2.7 which DOES trigger an unicode error. Does anyone have a way to specify which python version to use on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the Python version in your virtualenv command.

```
virtualenv dev_FirstDj_py35 --python=python3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias: just put

```
alias python=python3
```

in your ~/.bashrc file